# while scrolling element stop specific point

Tags: javascript, css

How can I stop element at the specific point while scrolling?

Here is my source code that I using.

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.s1, .s2, .s3 {
  height: 100vh;
}
.s1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.s2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 1px solid aqua;
}
.s3 {
  background-color: beige;
}
.s1 .p1 {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="s1">
    <p class="p1">TEST</p>
  </div>
  <div class="s2">
    <p class="p2">STOP HERE</p>
  </div>
  <div class="s3">
  
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Just simple code. I defined `position: fixed` to .s1's `<p>` tag.

So `<p>` always floating on center of screen while scrolling down or up.

While scrolling down, if .s1's `<p>` tag meet .s2's `<p>` tag, it have to stop.

Also if scrolling up, .s1's `<p>` tag have to move up.

I want to implement this issue with pure html/css/js.

But it is possible, it's ok to use library.
(Maybe it have to use parallax scrolling or other else..I don't know exactly)

Is there any solution here?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added a console log so that you can see when `.s1 p` touches `.s2 p` while scrolling.

```js
window.onload = function() {  
  let s1P = document.querySelector('.s1 p');
  let s2P = document.querySelector('.s2 p');

  let scroll = () => {
      let coordS1P = s1P.getBoundingClientRect();
      let coordS2P = s2P.getBoundingClientRect();

      // touched while scrolling down condition
      if(coordS1P.bottom > coordS2P.top && coordS1P.top < coordS2P.bottom) console.log('touched!');
      
      // touched while scrolling up condition
      else if(coordS1P.bottom > coordS2P.top && coordS1P.top < coordS2P.bottom) console.log('touched!');
  };
  
  window.addEventListener('scroll', scroll, true);
}
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.s1, .s2, .s3 {
  height: 100vh;
}
.s1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.s2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 1px solid aqua;
}
.s3 {
  background-color: beige;
}
.s1 .p1 {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
  <div class="s1">
    <p class="p1">TEST</p>
  </div>
  <div class="s2">
    <p class="p2">STOP HERE</p>
  </div>
  <div class="s3">
  
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Well, I can. But, the problem is then you'll not be able to see the scrolling up detection. Will that be okay?

Comment: Is it impossible scrolling up behavior that I said?

Answer (score 0):

You mean like this?

```js
let stop = $('#stop').offset().top - $(window).innerHeight() / 2;

$(window).on('scroll', function(){

  let depth = $(window).scrollTop();
  
  if ( stop <= (depth) ) {
   $('.p1').css('position', 'absolute');
    $('#stop').text('TEST');
  } else {
   $('.p1').css('position', 'fixed');
    $('#stop').text('');
  }

});
```

```css
body {
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
.s1, .s2, .s3 {
  height: 100vh;
}
.s1 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid green;
}
.s2 {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: aqua;
  border: 1px solid aqua;
}
.s3 {
  background-color: beige;
}
.s1 .p1 {
  position: fixed;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="s1">
  <p class="p1">TEST</p>
</div>
<div class="s2">
  <p class="p2" id="stop"></p>
</div>
<div class="s3"></div>
```

Comment: Similar with this. But `TEST` have to just stop. Not disappear.

Comment: User must do not notice about change motion. To feel like just stop that point.

Comment: Try now. The hard work is done. Now you have to think about how to finalize the UX/UI details ;)

Comment: Now I'm doing. After finish it, I will edit my post. Thanks for reply :)